# how can I send gif in whatsapp-web js

Tags: javascript, whatsapp, whatsapp-stickers

does anyone know a way? this is what I tried so far and the err I get:

```js
const media = MessageMedia.fromFilePath('C:/desktop/test.gif');
try {
    client.sendMessage(message.from, media, {sendMediaAsSticker: false});
} catch(e) {
    console.log(e);
}
```

```js
 throw new Error('Evaluation failed: ' + helper_js_1.helper.getExceptionMessage(exceptionDetails));
                  ^
Error: Evaluation failed:
```

I also tried to set `sendMediaAsSticker` to true and I also tried sending it with webp&mp4

Comment: you solved your question? I need the same :)

Answer (score 0):

you can use a mp4 file and send it as a GIF, this is how -

```
var user_gif = MessageMedia.fromFilePath("./images/gif_name.mp4")
client.on('message', message => {
    message.reply(user_gif, undefined, {"sendVideoAsGif": true})
});
```

note - the third arg on the `replay` function is actually an object from whatsapp-web called `MessageSendOptions`, if you'll look into its docs [here](https://docs.wwebjs.dev/global.html#MessageSendOptions.sendVideoAsGif) you can find the `sendVideoAsGif` option which allows you to do the above